# centos + mongo questions

Tags: centos, mongodb

Where does mongo install on centos? I want to remove some databases and file collections as well as uninstall it all together, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

As it inst a core package it all depends on where you told it to go when you compiled it, or where the package maintainer did.

have a look in `/etc/init.d/mongodb` and it should have an argument `--dbpath` that will tell you where the DB's are stored.

As for removing it; it really all depends how it was installed...

Comment: figured it out, had to look in /etc/mongod.conf for the stored paths, uninstalled it via the "yum" command and the removed the db directory.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb uses /data to store there database on ubuntu see if database is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the offical 10gen rpms it puts it in

```
/var/lib/mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to discover where an application is actually installed in a unix-like OS is to run `which [command]`, so in your case `which mongod` and `which mongo`.

The config files should be at /etc/mongodb.conf  In there you should see where the database files and log files are stored.